# (Pending)intent opens SMS Application if File doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-intentservice

I've got the following code:

```
//gallery is going to get open if notification is clicked.
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,photoURI);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);


//generate notification config and show notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel channel = NotificationHandler.generateChannel("MyChannelId","MyChannelTitle",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        NotificationHandler.generateMaterialBuilder(
                getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                channel.getId(),
                pendingIntent,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
                "File Downloaded",
                "Click to open File",
                "Download Manager",
                Notification.PRIORITY_MAX,
                true);

mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
int length = mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications().length;//add new record below isnted of replacing the current one
mNotificationManager.notify(length+1, mBuilder.build());
```

Basically, the code creates a image in a custom gallery folder (not shown in the code cause its irrelevant) and when the image get's created a create a notification which open the image when clicking on it. This works as expected.

However here is the issue:
If I go to the gallery folder and delete the image and then click on the notification, the notification automatically opens the sms(messages) application rather than showing "No App Found" for e.g:

[image: notification]

->

[image: sms application]

Is there any possibility to prevent opening the sms intent?

EDIT:
Here is the function which generates the `NotificationBuilder`:

```
public static NotificationCompat.Builder generateMaterialBuilder(Context appContext,
                                           String channelId,
                                           PendingIntent contentIntent,
                                           int smallIcon,
                                           String contentTitle,
                                           String contentText,
                                           String subText,
                                           int priority,
                                           boolean autoCancel) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext, channelId);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); //this intent will get called when notification is clicked
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    mBuilder.setContentText(contentText);
    mBuilder.setSubText(subText);
    mBuilder.setPriority(priority); //Show every detail on bar
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(autoCancel); //close notification when its being clicked

    return mBuilder;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: I am not aware of a gallery folder. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @blackapps no, its a custom folder in the gallery. not a "gallery folder". The gallery is the default android application which contains my custom folder inside of it.

Comment: That is not very specific. And there is no default Gallery app on Android devices.

Comment: `NotificationHandler.generateMaterialBuilder` Unknown. Can you please post code that we can copy/paste to try?

Comment: Ok. Looks better but how did you implement: NotificationHandler.generateChannel() ?

Comment: If the uri was invalid (for a non existing file) the app choosen by the user would complain.

Comment: Which extension has your file? I saw random apps opened with different extensions.

Comment: @blackapps My fileextention is JPG. Do you think changing the file extension would be the solution?